# Where to get and how to compile older android api samples

Tags: android

I honestly think Google really did not do a great job at keeping their Android documentation and training guides up to date. Numerous times I encountered situations where the documentation refers to samples that no longer exist.

Most recently I've been trying to learn about animation for Android.

Google seems to have a good API guide about animation:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

The guide refers to sample "com.example.android.apis.animation" in the API Demos sample.  If you click on the "API Demos" link on that page, it brings you to another page with other samples.

After a bit of searching, I found the older samples have been moved and they can now be downloaded from git using this command:

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development`

Once downloaded, the sample I am looking for can be found at "samples/ApiDemos". The only problem now is those samples don't have a build.gradle file. They must have been created at a time when gradle was not being used yet.

I am obviously new to Android and I am trying to learn the ropes. I am using android studio to build my projects. All the tutorials I've been reading use gradle to build the android application.

My question is in this post is (1) how to get to the older samples that are referred throughout the current Android API guides like the example above, I hope I have identified the correct git repo.  (2) How the heck can I compile those older samples.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) how to get to the older samples that are referred throughout the current Android API guides like the example above, I hope I have identified the correct git repo.

The only way is to google and try to find them. There is no central repo for old versions of those (at least none that I'm aware of)

> (2) How the heck can I compile those older samples.

Instead of opening those projects normally, close your current project (File > Close Project) and then choose "Import from Eclipse". This will look into all configs and generate a build.gradle for you.